# Blank areas while drawing Heighway Dragon in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I've been doing some exercises from matura exam and there was one to draw a heighway dragon.

The program should focus on two pairs of variables:

**x' = -0,4*x - 1**

**y' = -0,4*y + 0,1**

and

**x' = 0,76*x -0,4*y**

**y' = 0,4*x + 0,76*y**

At the start x = 1 and y = 1, then, count a new x and y using the formula of randomly taken pair shown above (50/50 chance) and mark the point (x,y) on the chart. Everything repeat 5000 times.

So I tried it using python but the problem is that when I've finally drawn a dragon, at the chart I could see it was not one constant drawing but it had blank areas as in the photo below. Is it still acceptable or I made any mistake? Is there any way to make it look like the correct one?

[My chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFdce.png)

[The correct one to compare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSGRF.png)

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random


x = 1
y = 1
sumx = 0
sumy = 0
max_x = 0
max_y = 0

for i in range(5000):

    rand = random.randint(0, 1)
    if rand == 0:
        x = (-0.4 * x) - 1
        y = (-0.4 * y) + 0.1
    else:
        x = (0.76 * x) - (0.4 * y)
        y = (0.4 * x) + (0.76 * y)
    if i >= 100:
        sumx += x
        sumy += y
        plt.plot(x, y, c='black', marker='P', markersize=6)

        if x > max_x:
            max_x = x
        if y > max_y:
            max_y = y

plt.show()
avg_x = sumx / 5000
avg_y = sumy / 5000
print(round(avg_x, 1), round(avg_y, 1))
print('maximum x: ' + str(max_x) + ', maximum y: ' + str(max_y))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the coordinates `x'` and `y'` are definitely calculated in the way you have written them above then your code is OK (although I'm not sure why you only start plotting once you've iterated 100 times).

**However,** calling pyplot's plot function is computationally expensive so I would suggest the following:

- calculate all your `x` and `y` values and store them in lists
- make one call to `plt.scatter` outside your for loop

this way the execution time for your code is drastically improved. I've done that in the following code, and also removed the condition that `i >= 100`. I also changed the way the random number was generated to see if this had an effect but it still produces a very similar output to the original code (see image below).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import sys

x = 1
y = 1
sumx = 0
sumy = 0
max_x = 0
max_y = 0

x_values = []
y_values = []

for i in range(5000):
    rand = random.uniform(0,1)
    if rand <= 0.5:
        x = ((-0.4 * x) - 1)
        y = ((-0.4 * y) + 0.1)
        x_values.append(x)
        y_values.append(y)
    else:
        x = ((0.76 * x) - (0.4 * y))
        y = ((0.4 * x) + (0.76 * y))
        x_values.append(x)
        y_values.append(y)
    sumx += x
    sumy += y

    if x > max_x:
        max_x = x
    if y > max_y:
        max_y = y

plt.scatter(x_values, y_values, c='black', marker='P')
plt.ylim([-1, 0.4])
plt.xlim([-1.5, 0.5])
plt.show()

avg_x = sumx / 5000
avg_y = sumy / 5000
print(round(avg_x, 1), round(avg_y, 1))
print('maximum x: ' + str(max_x) + ', maximum y: ' + str(max_y))
```

[image: dragon]

Comment: Okay so I've also tried to make these changes and got the same results, but if it's acceptable I don't really care about the appearance. Thanks for help.

Comment: And I had to start at 100th iteration, I forgot to mention but it doesn't really matter :)

Comment: @PatrykR did you notice the performance improvements with the changes?

Comment: So I tested the execution time of this program and it turned out that your suggestion takes approximately 0.5 seconds less to run than mine initial code. Not a huge difference but that's something.

Comment: @PatrykR on my first run of your code it was incredibly slow ([see here](https://imgur.com/9A955SD)). The difference is made even more clear if you increase the number of iterations in the `for loop`. Please don't take my comments as an attack on you or your coding, I'm just meaning to highlight a potential performance issue as you continue to code using matplotlib.

Comment: Well, I am not taking your comments as an attack - really. I just didn't get such nice results by running this using lists. Now I see you also made other modifications which turned out to be crucial here, because the difference is colossal. Thanks for your help and sorry for my oversight.